# boost::asio::async_write with forward traversal iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, boost-asio

I have a forward iterator which generates/handles bytes on-the-fly and I'd like to use use it as is to send data with `boost::asio::async_write`.

In fact, what I have is some custom developed iterator using [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library which has the Forward Traversal Iterator category. This iterator is used to generate some bytes and generate the SHA256 on-the-fly. Is there any way to send these bytes using `boost::asio::async_write` without the need to copy them into some buffer?

The code looks like that:

```
sha256hasher hasher;
auto on_the_fly_range = some_range_ctor|boost::adaptors::transformed(std::ref(hasher));

boost::asio::async_write(socket_, on_the_fly_range, [](auto const& ec, auto size){});
```

Don't worry, that hasher might go out of scope, in my case it'll not, this is just the simplified view. I am only interested, how to make `async_write` accepting `on_the_fly_range`. `on_the_fly_range` is very well copyable and will maintain the internal state.

I understand, that I can introduce a `for` loop, iterate through the `on_the_fly_range` create chunks of data and send them, but is there a more elegant way to do that without intermediate data prefetch?

Comment: To do this you need a push strategy. How many bytes will be enough to send? How many are to be expected? Just write a loop to copy the streams. Stream copy is still copy. Unless you copy a raw fd, in which case you might use `sendfile` or similar "splicing" APIs and act on the raw socket handle

Comment: the entire range would be enough to send. The range is not endless and is at most 65k long. But I have only forward iterator category. I am just wondering why it's not possible to send some bytes and let asio chunk them for me. It just forces many people to repeat the same code, instead of saying: we will chunk byte for you internally and make it efficient for 90% of the cases.

Comment: Asio does that. But only for existing buffer sequences. It might not be impossible to make a generic adaptor for that I suppose. I certainly don't think this is something that very often comes up. Usually you have the goods to send in tangible firm before sending

Comment: You are right for sure and I'd even be good without all the upper requirements, but than I started to write test code and want to calculate sha256 of sent data on the fly, and here we go! Ideally, I'd prefer asio to work with boost range library, than there are no limits :) In my case some_range_ctor is just a simple vector of random byte octets and asio is totally fine to accept it with `boost::asio::buffer(my_vector_of_pod_byte_octets)`. But now I just want every byte_octet go through a hasher and calculate sha2 on the fly.

Comment: I have a valid scenario for this, when a SPSC queue is plugged into the Boost Asio async_write. Feeding a forward iterator would be just amazing here.